# Best GPU and RAM upgrade for compaq elite 8300 sff

Tags: gpu, memory-management

I would like it to be equal or less than seven hundred dollars American.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And specifically for Blender 2.8. Thanks!

Comment: Also, (sorry for all the extra requests for expert opinion), whatever I need for extra PSU and case requirements are irrelevant, -I'll just get them. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference the [blender documentation for minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Cross refer these with [the specifications to your machine](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-elite-8300-ultra-slim-pc/5232866/document/c03345460#AbT2).

It looks like you would need a low-profile graphics card to fit in this case.  You should be aware that modifying OEM units like this is not a good starting point and that you may run into compatibility problems.  Contact HP support for more information.